# Como mostrar una imagen desde la web en un QMainWindow

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

quisiera saber como puedo mostrar una imagen traida desde una url destro del qmainwindow.

este es el codigo:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import uic 
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import cv2
import urllib.request
import numpy as np
from urllib.request import *
from PIL import Image




class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("gif.ui",self)

        self.table.setColumnWidth(0,200)
        print(self.table.item(1,1).text())

        url = 'http://www.chis.mx/boletincanaco/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Logo-Steren-Vertical-700x406.jpg'
        urlretrieve(url,'pic.jpg')

        img = Image.open('pic.jpg')
        img.show()



app = QApplication([])
p = Principal()
p.show()
app.exec_()
```

Pero me  muestra la imagen utilizando el visor de windows por default, y no la muestra destro del qmain window

este es otro archivo que trata de hacer lo mismo pero no muestra nada.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import uic 
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import cv2
import urllib.request
import numpy as np




class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("gif.ui",self)

        self.table.setColumnWidth(0,200)
        print(self.table.item(1,1).text())
        self.url_to_image('http://www.chis.mx/boletincanaco/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Logo-Steren-Vertical-700x406.jpg')

    def url_to_image(sel,url):
        resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()),dtype="uint8")
        image = cv2.imdecode(image,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        print(image)
        return image



app = QApplication([])
p = Principal()
p.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No debes usar urllib ya que es bloqueante, tendrías que ejecutarlo en un hilo, pero en vez de ello puedes usar `QNetworkAccessManager` que permite enviar solicitudes y recibir respuestas de la red.

Por otro lado para mostrar una imagen puedes usar QLabel.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtNetwork

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.label)

        url = 'http://www.chis.mx/boletincanaco/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Logo-Steren-Vertical-700x406.jpg'
        manager = QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager(self)
        manager.finished.connect(self.onFinished)
        manager.get(QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest(QtCore.QUrl(url)))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtNetwork.QNetworkReply)
    def onFinished(self, reply):
        image = QtGui.QImage.fromData(reply.readAll())
        if not image.isNull():
            self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image))
        reply.deleteLater()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este método funciona si la url marca a la imagen directamente, servicios de almacenamiento como drive, dropbox, etc no muestran la url directa de la imagen aun cuando indicas que lo compartan.

---

Por ejemplo en el caso de Google Drive, debes hacer click derecho sobre la imagen y seleccionar *Obtener enlace para Compartir*:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

obteniendo una url con el siguiente formato:

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=[IMAGE-ID]
```

donde IMAGE-ID es el identificador de la imagen, para obtener la url correcto usar el siguiente formato:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=[IMAGE-ID]
```

El siguiente script lo hace directamente:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtNetwork

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.label)

        share_url = 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PakzAn-XPIT3TalZZmuo1wtmDomnnRaE'
        share_id = QtCore.QUrlQuery(QtCore.QUrl(share_url).query()).queryItemValue("id")

        manager = QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager(self)
        manager.finished.connect(self.onFinished)
        url = QtCore.QUrl("https://drive.google.com/uc")
        params = QtCore.QUrlQuery()
        params.addQueryItem("export", "download")
        params.addQueryItem("id", share_id)
        url.setQuery(params)
        req = QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest(url)
        req.setAttribute(QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest.FollowRedirectsAttribute, True)
        manager.get(req)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtNetwork.QNetworkReply)
    def onFinished(self, reply):
        image = QtGui.QImage.fromData(reply.readAll())
        if not image.isNull():
            self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: exelente respuesta.

Comment: solo una pregunta a que te rieres con que urllib es bloqueante

Comment: @Revsky01 Descargar un archivo involucra un tiempo, no es instantaneo, por otro lado la GUI se ejecuta en un eventloop, este eventloop le permite manejar los eventos del teclado, mouse, etc por lo que uno tarea que demore mas de un segundo, digamos 30 segundos evitaria la interaccion con la GUI, por ejemplo no podrias redimensionar la GUI, esta se congelaria haciendo que tu aplicacion se cierre, quizas lo hayas observado al hacer una consulta a firebase o usa time.sleep(10) para que veas el efecto desagradable

Comment: Ok Muchas gracias...

Comment: sin duda eres el mejor en python :)